# jQuery LayerSlider: LayerSlider not working with single image in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using LayerSlider (http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-jquery-full-width-slider/) which is working fine on all browsers except IE 10. Even the demo link is working fine on the browser but when I integrate the slider in the website I am working on, it fails to load the image and the following error is shown in the console:

```
"It seems like the URL of the image or background image "image name" is pointing to a wrong location and it cannot be loaded. Please check the URLs of all your images used in the slider."
```

The link of the image is correct and the issue appears if only one image is added. If more than one image is added, then the above error does not show.

I have checked for compatibility issues with other plugins by disabling other jQuery plugins but still no effect. I even tried to use the same version of jQuery the demo is using but still no luck.

If anyone has an idea what the problem is, kindly help me out
Thanks